# get p value based on observed F and critical F

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons

When conducting multiple comparisons, I can calculate a critical value via whatever method is appropriate for the situation. If the adjustment method I need is a common one such as Bonferroni, I can use p.adjust() in R to get the adjusted p-value. If I calculate a less common CV for F, though, such as using the Scheffe method, there's no function I've found that will give me an adjusted p-value.

There must be a general formula for calculating an adjusted p-value based on the observed F and the critical F, but I can't find it and the professor for my class hasn't been able to find it either.

I should note that although my question has come about due to a class, it's not something being covered in class and I want to know for purposes of real-life application.

Comment: See `scheffe.test` in package agricolae.